# Deleted my desktop

Tags: delete, undelete

I accidently dragged this thing in my home folder under home called Desktop (image of standard ubuntu thing) into the trash. Freakng out. HOw do I undo it. My desktop is gone.

Comment: I have updated my answer, no need to goto recovery just use other tty by pressing Crtl+Alt+F1 and follow steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't empty the trash already, just go to your trash folder with the file manager, right-click on your desktop and click "Restore".

Comment: Thats the thing, it never actually went into the trash but then I restarted the machine and my desktop was blank

Comment: Try to open a terminal and type `mv .local/share/Trash/Desktop .` (note the final dot, and the space before it).

Comment: mv: cannot stat `.local/share/Trash/Desktop': No such file or directory

Comment: What does `ls .local/share/Trash` say ?

Comment: lolly@tofu:~$ ls .local/share/Trash
expunged  files  info

Comment: And what does `ls .local/share/Trash/files` say ?

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: It's weird, a moment ago you said that `.local/share/Trash` contains `expunged files info`, so this last command should at worst return nothing, but not an error.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea

Comment: wait wait wait it says  bash: .local/share/Trash: Is a directory

Comment: I think you didn't type the commands correctly. Again, please retry `ls .local/share/Trash/files` in a freshly opened terminal.

Comment: redid it, last time was without list, it had no response

Comment: This means your trash is indeed empty. I'm afraid your files are gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal, if you cannot open terminal, goto other tty ( Press Crtl + Alt + F1 ), enter your username and password, then execute following commands :

**Note : Unix is case sensitive, thus look at commands carefully**

```
mkdir dd
cp -R ~/.local/share/Trash/files ~/dd
```

This will copy all your files from Trash into Desktop folder.

Then execute this commands in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop --purge && rm -f .config .gnome .gnome2 .compiz .kde .local .cache && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Restart and it will be ok.

Comment: K ill try, but how do i boot into recovery mode? Like f8 or something?

Comment: It says no such file or directory